# What is the best Visual Studio Plugin for Printing Code

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

Some of the features I think it must include are:

1. Print Entire Solution
2. Ability to print line numbers
3. Proper choice of coding font and size to improve readability
4. Nice Header Information
5. Ability to print regions collapsed

Couple feature additions:

1. Automatically insert page breaks
   after methods/classes
2. Keep long lines readable (nearly all
   current implementations are broken)

*Note: There are many reasons to need to print code... One very good one is escrow.*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I use [PrettyCode.Print for .NET](http://submain.com/?nav=products.pcp.net). It does everything on your list, and more. (I use it for printing code excerpts for copyright registration paperwork, which is similar to your escrow case.)

It is a little slow to open a really big solution, but not unbearably so, and the output quality is excellent.

Comment: the product was discontinued, and officially supports only VS2003, VS2005, and VS2008. yet, It has successfully opened VS2012 solution.

Answer (score 4):

Try StarPrint's [VSNETcodePrint](http://starprint2000.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Couple feature additions:

- Automatically insert page breaks after methods/classes
- Keep long lines readable (nearly all current implementations are broken)